Live Radio Chrome Casting Android
Im trying to handle sending meta data to the receiver chrome cast using this method
private fun updateMetadataWithoutReloading() {
        if (castSession != null) {
            val remoteMediaClient = castSession!!.remoteMediaClient

            // Check if the remote media client and current item exist
            if (remoteMediaClient != null && remoteMediaClient.currentItem != null) {
                val mediaItem = remoteMediaClient.currentItem

                // Update metadata directly in the current item
                val metadata = mediaItem?.media?.metadata
                if (metadata != null) {

                    metadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, title)
                    metadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ARTIST, artist)
                    metadata.addImage(WebImage(Uri.parse(image)))
                    // Trigger a status update to force Chromecast to refresh metadata
                    remoteMediaClient.requestStatus()

                    Log.d("Cast", "Metadata updated on Chromecast without reloading the stream")
                } else {
                    Log.d("Cast", "No metadata found in the current item")
                }
            }
        }
    }

But I see there's no result on TV, The only way to change meta data is to reload it.
I'm using this to set it up:
private fun handleCastSession(session: CastSession?) {
        session?.let { castSession ->
            val remoteMediaClient: RemoteMediaClient? = castSession.remoteMediaClient
            if (remoteMediaClient != null && castSession.isConnected) {
                val metadata = MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC_TRACK).apply {
                    putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, title)
                    putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ARTIST, artist)
                    addImage(WebImage(Uri.parse(image)))
                }
                val mediaInfo = listenUrl?.let {
                    MediaInfo.Builder(it)
                        .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
                        .setContentType("audio/mp3")
                        .setMetadata(metadata)
                        .build()
                }
                if (mediaInfo != null) {
                    remoteMediaClient.load(mediaInfo,true,0)
                    muteMobileAudio()
                    Log.d("Cast", "Media loaded to Chromecast")
                }
            }
        }
    }

I don't want to keep loading since it leads to loading and buffering for like 3-7 seconds!
Any help?
Trying to update Meta data on chrome casting
